# MS Regedit Hex to Date Conversion

Tags: conversion, date-time, regedit, hexadecimal

I'm trying to analyze my redundant network profiles on Win 10 via registry path:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`

However, I'm unable to interpret the date from the hex format representation.

Eg:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{GUID}]
"ProfileName"="XXXXXXXXX"
"Description"="XXXXXXXXX"
"Managed"=dword:00000000
"Category"=dword:00000000
"DateCreated"=hex:e4,07,05,00,04,00,0e,00,14,00,16,00,06,00,8b,01
"NameType"=dword:00000047
"DateLastConnected"=hex:e4,07,05,00,04,00,0e,00,14,00,30,00,30,00,04,03
```

How can I convert the hex `e4,07,05,00,04,00,0e,00,14,00,16,00,06,00,8b,01` to something more readable?
A reusable solution would be more helpful.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202411/read-registery-value-and-convert-to-date

Comment: Thanks. I tried the PowerShell script suggested in that thread. At least, I'm getting some date now. But the value is incorrect. For Eg. the last connection date for the network that I'm currently using is converted as 31 January 1625 07:51:06.

Comment: See edit made on my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 possible methods:

**Manually**

The third method is described [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/49285198_Forensic_Analysis_of_the_Windows_7_Registry) for Windows 7, but it is also working with Windows 10. Applying the method described on that page, gives the following steps:

1. Convert your date from little endian to big endian. For example, your date create is: `e407 0500 0400 0e00 1400 1600 0600 8b01` (I have put the spaces to better visualize).  To convert to big endian, swap every 2 bytes, you will get `07e4 0005 0004 000e 0014 0016 0006 018b`
2. You get the year from converting `07e4` to decimal: 2020.
3. The month `00005` to decimal: 5 = May
4. Then the day of the week `0004` to decimal: 4 = Thursday
5. The day `000e` to decimal: 14 = 14th day of the month
6. The hour `0014` to decimal: 20 = 20:00 or 08:00 PM
7. The minutes `0016` to decimal: 22 = 22 minutes
8. The seconds `0006` to decimal: 6 = 6 seconds
9. The thousandth seconds `018b` to decimal: 395 = 0.395 second.

Your created date is/was 2020 May 14, 20:22:06.395.

**Using Powershell**

You can try to use PowerShell as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202411/read-registery-value-and-convert-to-date).

**Using DCode**

Another possibility is to use [Dcode](https://www.digital-detective.net/dcode/). Insert the hex date you want to convert, select Hexadecimal (Little Endian) as the format then click on Decode button.

[image]

Comment: That' great! I found a similar approach to the first one here: http://cfed-ttf.blogspot.com/2009/08/decoding-datecreated-and.html but yours is even easier to understand. Plus the DCode tool is great and works flawlessly. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Using Python 3.9:

```
n=list(map(str,input("Enter Hex value : ").split(",")))
l1=[]
l2=[]
for i in range(0,len(n),2):
  l1.append(n[i])
for j in range(1,len(n),2):
  l2.append(n[j])

l3=[str (x) + str (y) for x, y in zip (l2, l1)]
print("Date (YYYY/MM/DD): ")
for i in range(len(l3)):
  if i!=2 and i<4:
    res = int(l3[i], 16)
    print(res,end="/")

print("\n")
print("Time (HH:mm:ss:ms): ")
for i in range(len(l3)):
  if i>3:
    res = int(l3[i], 16)
    print(res,end=":")
```